# How to write "Having" condition inside a SQL Pivot query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, case

```
select * from
(
SELECT datename( Month,soh.OrderDate)[Month], sd.OrderQty as orderQty
from Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh
join Sales.SalesOrderDetail sd
on soh.SalesOrderID = sd.SalesOrderID
)t
pivot(
sum(orderQty)
for [month] in ([january],[february],[march],[april],[may],[june],[july],[august],[september],[october],[november],[december]) )as pivot_table
```

This query is giving TotalOrderQuantity based on Month, but I have to filter by the condition :
having SUM(sd.OrderQty)>50

My query without Pivoting would be this:

```
    SELECT datename( Month,soh.OrderDate)[Month], SUM(sd.OrderQty) as orderQty
    from Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh
    join Sales.SalesOrderDetail sd
    on soh.SalesOrderID = sd.SalesOrderID
    group by datename( Month,soh.OrderDate)
    having SUM(sd.OrderQty)>50
```

Comment: What is the issue with your query ?

Answer (score 1):

**Use your correct query inside pivot:-**

```
select * from
(
SELECT datename( Month,soh.OrderDate)[Month], SUM(sd.OrderQty) as orderQty
from Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh
join Sales.SalesOrderDetail sd
on soh.SalesOrderID = sd.SalesOrderID
group by datename( Month,soh.OrderDate)
having SUM(sd.OrderQty)>50
)t
pivot(
sum(orderQty)
for [month] in ([january],[february],[march],[april],[may],[june],[july],[august], 
[september],[october],[november],[december]) )as pivot_table
```

Comment: Thanks, it's helpful. I had made a mistake in using alias after pivot i.e. sum(orderQty).

Comment: @Anu if answer is correct then mark as correct, which helps to other.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when month(soh.OrderDate) = 1 then sd.OrderQty end) as jan,
       sum(case when month(soh.OrderDate) = 2 then sd.OrderQty end) as feb,
       . . .
       sum(case when month(soh.OrderDate) = 12 then sd.OrderQty end) as dec
from Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh join
     Sales.SalesOrderDetail sd
     on soh.SalesOrderID = sd.SalesOrderID
having sum(sd.OrderQty) > 50;
```

I strongly suspect that you want multiple rows in the result set, in which case you would have an explicit `GROUP BY`:

```
select <something>
       sum(case when month(soh.OrderDate) = 1 then sd.OrderQty end) as jan,
       sum(case when month(soh.OrderDate) = 2 then sd.OrderQty end) as feb,
       . . .  -- fill in the other months here
       sum(case when month(soh.OrderDate) = 12 then sd.OrderQty end) as dec
from Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh join
     Sales.SalesOrderDetail sd
     on soh.SalesOrderID = sd.SalesOrderID
group by <something>
having sum(sd.OrderQty) > 50;
```

Comment: In the query you have mentioned, HAVING is not working, it's not filtering the SUM(OrderQty) >50 and yeah I understand that if we have GroupBy we get multiple rows. Since I have to filter, I am using it. What is the alternate solution to get one row and use having condition as well? Please let me know!

Comment: @Anu . . . `HAVING` should work without `GROUP BY`.  If the one row does not meet the condition, the query then returns no rows.